# How to derive this equality by change of variables for the Riemann integral?

Tags: calculus

Define $\mathrm{Diff}_h (f) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Why is the following true?

$$ \int_u^v \mathrm{Diff}_h (f)\ dx = \frac{1}{h}\int_0^hf(v+t)-f(u+t)dt $$

Note: this is from Royden's real analysis page 122.

Comment: I think your first integral is a bit misrepresented.

Comment: double checked. seems to be correct.

Comment: I can't really understand what your first integral is. Is it perhaps supposed to be:

$$\int_u^v \text{Diff}_hf \, dx=\int_u^v \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\, dx$$

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ has anti-derivative $F$. Then the first integral is
$$
\frac{F(v+h) - F(v) - F(u+h) + F(u)}{h}
$$
and the second is
$$
\frac{F(v+h) - F(u+h) - F(v) + F(u)}{h}
$$
and they are the same as claimed.